# Find population mean probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I would like your help on the following.

**The problem**
We have N persons and Y boxes. What is the mean person’s probability of choosing the same box with another one? (I want the probability of the whole population, not the case on which at least one of the N people choose the same box with another one).

**Further Explanation**
So let's say we have 100 persons outside a building and 1000 boxes in the building. The procedure is that we put the persons inside the building (one by one) and they choose only one box. On the end , how many will have chosen a box that none else have chose it and how many would choose a box that another person have chosen it.

**My try/approach**
I tried to find the solution with the Birthday Paradox Theory. But I think that this not helps me for 2 reasons:

1. This theory talks about *at least* one person.So I think there is a gap on handling my problem with this.
2. I am not covered on the following scenario. Let's say that the person G chooses a box for first time. On this time , this person belongs to the group with the persons who have chosen unique boxes.Then a person Z chooses the same box with the user G. Then , both of them will belong to the other group of persons. And this will be the final result for them also.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice , I will improve my question.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the question. Does each person choose a certain number of boxes? what does "choosing the same box with another one" mean?

Comment: Yes , I have retyped the question. I hope now , it is more clear.